Non blocking rest api using spring webflux
I have a requirement to make dashboard non blocking rest api having below details :

Customer profile -- coming from 3rd party api
Customer Accounts -- coming from another 3rd party api
Customer bene list -- coming from db

response structure is something like this :
 {
        "profile": {
            "id": "123",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "john.doe@example.com"
        },
        "accounts": {
            "accountNumber": "ACC-456",
            "balance": 1000.0
        },
        "beneficiaries": [
            {
                "name": "John Doe Sister",
                "address": "XYX"
            }
        ]
    }

in above if any response comes 1st our API should return same and update same response object with data when received like if accounts api gives data 1st then we shou;d not wait for profile and bene results just like stream of data when ever it comes our api sending same.
Tried below code but requirement is not getting fulfilling.
public Flux<CustomerDashboardDTO> getCustomerDashboard(String customerId) {

    // Create a Mono for profile and beneficiaries
    Mono<CustomerProfile> profileMono = Mono.just(createDummyProfile());
    Mono<List<BeneficiaryDetails>> beneficiariesMono = Mono.just(createBene());
    // Create a Flux to emit the initial data
    return Mono.zip(profileMono, beneficiariesMono)
          .flatMapMany(tuple -> {
              // Create the dashboardDTO and set profile and beneficiaries
              CustomerDashboardDTO dashboardDTO = new CustomerDashboardDTO();
              dashboardDTO.setProfile(tuple.getT1());
              dashboardDTO.setBeneficiaries(tuple.getT2());
              

              // Emit the initial DTO immediately
              Flux<CustomerDashboardDTO> initialEmission = Flux.just(dashboardDTO);

              // After a delay, fetch accounts and update the DTO
              Mono<CustomerDashboardDTO> updatedEmission = Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                    .flatMap(delay -> {
                        CustomerAccount account = createDummyAccounts(); // Fetch accounts
                        dashboardDTO.setAccounts(account); // Update DTO with accounts
                        return Mono.just(dashboardDTO); // Emit the updated DTO
                    });

              // Combine initial and updated emissions
              return initialEmission.concatWith(updatedEmission);
          })
          .doOnNext(dto -> System.out.println("Emitting DTO: " + dto)); // Log emission
}

This code is returning response like below and that too after delay of 10 sec.
   {
    "profile": {
        "id": "123",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "john.doe@example.com"
    },
    "accounts": null,
    "beneficiaries": [
        {
            "name": "John Doe sister",
            "address": "xyx"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "profile": {
        "id": "123",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "john.doe@example.com"
    },
    "accounts": {
        "accountNumber": "ACC-456",
        "balance": 1000.0
    },
    "beneficiaries": [
        {
            "name": "John Doe Sister",
            "address": "XYX"
        }
    ]
}

Please help trying to solve this from last 2-3 days. I am also new in reactive programming.

It would be helpful if you can point to what exact problem you have.

@IgorArtamonov the problem statement is current implementation is giving me two instance of CustomerDashboardDTO and that too after 10 sec but expected is one object of CustomerDashboardDTO when we receive profile and bene and same object will get update as soon we get accounts.

Right, that's exactly what you do in the code. You return two instances at return initialEmission.concatWith(updatedEmission);

@IgorArtamonov can you please help me how to send only one emission with initial response and update same with account info also in same emission

That makes them two. Not one.

@IgorArtamonov can you please help with correction in code ?

You cannot return one element but return two. You have to decided do you need one or two.

I'm not sure to have understood fully the question.

current implementation is giving me two instance of CustomerDashboardDTO and that too after 10 sec but expected is one object of CustomerDashboardDTO when we receive profile and bene and same object will get update as soon we get accounts.

If what you're looking for is to combine the three sources and wait for all of them before emitting, why not zipping the three sources?
public Mono<CustomerDashboardDTO> getCustomerDashboard() {

        Mono<CustomerProfile> customerProfile = findCustomerProfile();
        Mono<List<BeneficiaryDetails>> beneficiaries = findBeneficiaryDetails();
        Mono<Account> account = Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .flatMap(delay -> findAccount());

        return Mono.zip(customerProfile, account, beneficiaries)
            .map(t -> new CustomerDashboardDTO(t.getT1(), t.getT2(), t.getT3()));
}

